# Passing two different dynamically allocated arrays to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to pass two arrays (one NxN, one 1XN) allocated on the heap to a function. I keep getting segmentation fault 11. According to `gdb`, the seg fault occurs at `double c=matrix[i][j]/matrix[j][j]`. I can't help but feel that the issue is with how I am declaring the parameters in the function.

```
double **Mat_A=(double **) malloc(dim_matrix*sizeof(double));
double *Vec_B=(double *) malloc(dim_vector*sizeof(double));

//read in numbers from file
for(int i=0; i<dim_matrix; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<dim_matrix; j++)
  {
    fscanf(f1, "%lf%*[^\n]%*c", &Mat_A[i][j]);
  }
}
for(int k=0; k<dim_vector; k++)
{
  fscanf(f2, "%lf%*[^\n]%*c", &Vec_B[k]);
}

void reduce_mat(double **matrix, double *vector, int row, int column)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for( j = 0; j < row; j++ )
    {
        for( i = 0; i < column; i++ )
        {
            if ( i != j )
            {
                double c= matrix[i][j] / matrix[j][j];
                for( int k = 0; k < column + 1; k++ )
                {
                    matrix[i][k] = matrix[i][k] - c * matrix[j][k];
                }
            }
         }
      }
      printf("\nSolution:\n");
      for(i=0; i<column; i++)
        {
          vector[i]=matrix[i][column+1]/matrix[i][i];
          printf("\nx%d=%f\n",i,vector[i]);
        }
      return;
```

Comment: Where is `row` and `column` computed? Please show the `reduce_mat` call-site.

Comment: `(double **) malloc(dim_matrix*sizeof(double)` is suspicious.  I'd expect `malloc(dim_matrix*sizeof(double*)` or better `malloc(dim_matrix * sizeof *Mat_A`.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/), to see how to allocate memory for a 2D array.

Comment: @chux could you explain why this is suspicious? I have very little experience with arrays.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your problem is that you claim to pass an array of pointers but you don't pass an array of pointers.  You could probably use `void reduce_mat(int row, inc col, double matrix[row][col], double vector[row]) { … }` to good effect (or you might need `double vector[col]` — though the code would work the same whichever you used, funnily enough).  And you'd have `double (*matrix)[col] = malloc(row * col * sizeof(matrix[0][0]));` to allocate the memory — note the revised type.  Assumes C99 and VLA (variable length array) support, or C11 where the support is not denied.

Comment: `malloc(dim_matrix*sizeof(double));` is allocating memory for a number of `double`s.  That returns a pointer to those `double`s. a `double *`, not a `double **`.

Comment: "I am trying to pass two arrays (one NxN, one 1XN) allocated on the heap to a function. I keep getting segmentation fault 11."  + "I have very little experience with arrays" --> Start with sometime simpler like allocate a 1D array, assign the values and print them.  After mastering that, tackle 2D (allocate, assign, print).  Then come back to this task.

Comment: @chux I would, but alas, this is an assignment.

Comment: @Hannah Certainly the assignment does not prevent one from trying simpler sub-tasks first.  In the end - this approach will be faster and less frustrating  Good luck.

Comment: Show the _actual_ code you use to allocate the matrix.  If this is all you have, then you must understand that all you did was allocate a vector of uninitialized pointers to non-existent rows in your matrix.  You need to allocate storage for those rows and initialize the row pointers accordingly.

Comment: To be perhaps clearer, the allocation of your pseudo-matrix is plain *wrong*. Even if the size of the pointer array would be correct (which it isn't) you'd also have to allocated your individual lines. I can't believe how many teachers are still out there that start teaching pointer-to-pointer cruft, before acutally explaining simple matrices.

Comment: @JensGustedt thanks, and agreed, the class has left me groping in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `column` is the ordinal number of columns in the matrix, so if the value is `5` then the columns have indexes `0..4`.

However inside your `if( i != j )...` statement, you have this:

```
k < column + 1 // so `k == column` can be true
...
matrix[i][k]
```

Which means you're dereferencing the `matrix` pointer with an offset `i * row + k` which may be out-of-bounds.

This assumes that the matrix' buffer does not have excess space at the end of each row (for additional columns) nor additional rows at the end of the buffer.

Comment: Are you saying to remove the +1? I tried, it did not fix the seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give any indication of the shape of your matrix, I tried with a non-square matrix.  Things didn't seem to work as well as with a square matrix, so the code shown works with a 6x6 square matrix and a vector of size 6.

Here's code that works OK for me on a Mac running macOS 10.13.1 High Sierra, using GCC 7.2.0.  It reads all the data from standard input; it writes to standard output.

The `dump_matrix()` and `dump_vector()` functions are representative of a useful class of function that dumps a data structure in a readable format.  More general versions take the file stream as the first argument, and the include a `fflush(fp)` at the end, and probably check for non-null pointers.  Sometimes, it helps to print the address too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void reduce_mat(int row, int col, double matrix[row][col], double vector[col]);

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int row, int col, double matrix[row][col]);
static void dump_vector(const char *tag, int col, double vector[col]);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f1 = stdin;
    int row = 6;
    //int col = 8;
    int col = 6;

    double (*Mat_A)[col] = malloc(row * col * sizeof(double));
    double *Vec_B =  malloc(col * sizeof(double));

    // read in numbers from standard input
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (fscanf(f1, "%lf", &Mat_A[i][j]) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Read error matrix[%d,%d]\n", i, j);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < col; k++)
    {
        if (fscanf(f1, "%lf", &Vec_B[k]) != 1)      // Beware - changed to f1
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Read error vector[%d]\n", k);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    dump_matrix("Matrix A", row, col, Mat_A);
    dump_vector("Vector B", col, Vec_B);

    reduce_mat(row, col, Mat_A, Vec_B);

    dump_vector("Solution Vector", col, Vec_B);
    dump_matrix("Reduced  Matrix", row, col, Mat_A);

    free(Mat_A);
    free(Vec_B);

    return 0;
}

static void reduce_mat(int row, int col, double matrix[row][col], double vector[col])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                double c = matrix[i][j] / matrix[j][j];
                for (int k = 0; k < col + 1; k++)
                {
                    matrix[i][k] = matrix[i][k] - c * matrix[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nSolution:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = matrix[i][col + 1] / matrix[i][i];
        printf("x%d = %9.2f\n", i, vector[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int row, int col, double matrix[row][col])
{
    printf("%s (matrix[%d][%d]):\n", tag, row, col);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("%9.2f", matrix[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static void dump_vector(const char *tag, int col, double vector[col])
{
    printf("%s (vector[%d]):\n", tag, col);
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        printf("%9.2f", vector[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Given an input file containing 42 random floating point numbers between 0 and 1000, this produces:

```
Matrix A (matrix[6][6]):
   994.60   955.00   769.60    32.10   950.10   555.90
   105.50   857.50   606.10   289.30   592.60    95.60
   437.50    90.20   264.10   262.40   879.00   708.20
   236.40     1.00   273.90   405.60     4.80   199.90
   114.90   713.70   433.90   739.00    42.10   184.80
   895.40   911.00   161.80   829.20   487.90   864.80
Vector B (vector[6]):
   543.10   258.70   556.60   101.50   685.30   899.30

Solution:
x0 =      0.76
x1 =      0.00
x2 =      0.00
x3 =     -0.00
x4 =     -0.00
x5 =     -0.00

Solution Vector (vector[6]):
     0.76     0.00     0.00    -0.00    -0.00    -0.00
Reduced  Matrix (matrix[6][6]):
   994.60     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
     0.00   756.20     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
    -0.00     0.00   154.36     0.00     0.00     0.00
    -0.00     0.00     0.00  -115.16     0.00     0.00
    -0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00 -7025.36     0.00
    -0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00  -237.16
```

I've no idea whether that's an appropriate calculation or not, but that isn't changed from the code in the question AFAICT (any such change is accidental and unintentional).  The types of the function matrix parameters are modified to be simpler to manage, and the memory allocation is assigned to an appropriate pointer to an array of `double` values.  Note that for a 6x6 array, using dynamic memory allocation is really not necessary; ordinary allocation on the stack would work fine.

Aren't variable length arrays (VLAs) useful?  They do simplify an awful lot of matrix manipulation code.

For on-stack allocation of a VLA, you do need to be cautious that there's enough space for the stack.  If there isn't, your program will probably crash.